# keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey not called for all attributes

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, key-value-observing

I am trying to observe changes to a transient attribute in my entity that is dependent on other attributes in the same entity. I want to do this by implementing `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`. The problem is that this doesn't seem to be invoked for all the attributes in the entity.

My entity has 10 attributes and about 5-6 relationships, and the keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey is called 5 or 6 times with some mix of attributes and relationships, but not all of them, including the transient attribute that I'm really interested in.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"todoSectionTitle"])
    {
        NSSet *affectingKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"todoStatus", @"todoStartDate", @"timeNow", nil];
        keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObjectsFromSet:affectingKeys];
    }
    return keyPaths;
}
```

In this case, keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey is called multiple times, but the key is never "todoSectionTitle" (a transient attribute). Neither is the key ever equal to "todoStatus" though that is a non-transient attribute. The key IS equal to "todoStartDate" in one of the times it is called. It can also be equal

What is the logic behind when `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` and which keys it is called for, and which keys it ignores? The docs don't seem to shed any light on this.

Comment: Is something key-value observing the `todoSectionTitle` property? KVO has no reason to call `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` except for keys actually being observed. In fact, KVO has no way of knowing what keys to call it with unless and until something attempts to observe such a key.

Comment: Not explicitly. I wonder why it does invoke the `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` for some keys though? I use Cocoa Bindings to bind some of those keys in my views ... would that explain why it works in some cases (like `todoStartDate`) and not others?

Comment: If you're using Coca Bindings, then this question should not be tagged with iOS.

Comment: It's a general question about KVO; but I'll remove the iOS tag.

Comment: It does look like observing the `todoSectionTitle` is needed for the `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` to be called with that key. If you implement Cocoa Bindings for some keys, you get the observer (and hence, `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`) for free.

Comment: Yes, Bindings is built on KVO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` is part of Key-Value Observing (KVO). KVO only needs to call it if something observes a key on an instance of the class which implements it. (That includes any keys observed indirectly. For example, if something observes key "A", it will call the method for key "A". If it indicates that the value of "A" is affected by key "B", then it will also call it for key "B" to see if some other key(s) affect the value of "B".)

If nothing is observing `todoSectionTitle` or any key whose value is affected by `todoSectionTitle`, then KVO has no reason to call `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` with "todoSectionTitle". In fact, KVO no way to know that there is such a key.

Bindings are built on top of KVO, so all of this applies to them, too.